# php - replace \n with <br> when saving back to database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I just thought i'd say first, i have tried searching for this elsewhere and there are plenty of answers for just replacing `\n` with a `<br>` tag.

However im having a bit of a strange issue.

I have a textbox that is populated with text from a database.
[image]

This is loaded using this **php**:

```
if (isset($_POST['sqlnoteid'])) 
    {
        if (empty($_POST['sqlnoteid'])) 
        {
            $notes = 'No Data';
        }
        if (sqlsrv_has_rows($stmt)) 
        {
            $data = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);

            echo "<div class='custom-font title-container'>
                    <div class='expand-button-container fa fa-expand' onclick='expandWindow()'></div>
                    <div id='title-container1'><div class='edit-note fa fa-pencil' onclick='editSQLNote()'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>" . "<div data-toggle='modal' data-target='#editSQLNoteNameModal' class='display-inline'>" . $data['SQLNoteName'] . "</div>" . "&nbsp;<div class='save-note fa fa-thumbs-up' onclick='saveSQLNote(); submitSQLNoteText();'></div></div>
                  </div>";

            $note = nl2br($data['SQLNote']);
            $note = preg_replace('%(SELECT|FROM|WHERE|INNER|JOIN|DISTINCT|LEFT|OUTER|APPLY|WITH|NOLOCK|DECLARE|ORDER BY|VARCHAR|bit)%m', '<span style="color: red;">$1</span>', $note);
            $note = preg_replace('%(ISNULL|UPDATE|SET|INSERT INTO)%m', '<span style="color: #9A2EFE;">$1</span>', $note);          
            $note = preg_replace('%(IS NOT NULL|AND|IS NULL)%m', '<span style="color: grey;">$1</span>', $note);
            $note = preg_replace('%(BEGIN TRAN|ROLLBACK TRAN|BEGIN|END|CASE|END|WHEN|THEN|ELSE)%m', '<span style="color: blue;">$1</span>', $note);
            $note = preg_replace('%(GETDATE|MAX|CONVERT|UPDATE|CAST|COUNT)%m', '<span style="color: #FA58F4;">$1</span>', $note);
            $note = preg_replace('%(@.+?\b)%m', '<span style="color: #009EC0; font-style: italic;">$1</span>', $note);
            $note = preg_replace('%(\[(.+?)\])%m', '<span style="font-weight: bold;">$1</span>', $note);
            $note = preg_replace('%(--.+?\n)%m', '<span style="color: green;">$1</span>', $note);
            $note = preg_replace('%(codestart)%m', '<code>', $note);
            $note = preg_replace('%(codeend)%m', '</code>', $note);

            echo "<div contenteditable='false' id='ta4'>" . $note . "</div>";
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo "No data found";
        }
    }
```

I can then click the pencil icon and using ajax, edit the note and click the thumbs up and save it straight back to the database

So if i put in a `<br>` as seen here:[image]

then submit that change, and it does replace like so:[image]

I can now refresh the page, etc and its fine. Until i make another edit and it has to load the note from the database again.

If i add the word stackoverflow in there, it will now reload the note with the word but we no longer have our line break:
[image]

this is the code i use to submit back to the database when saving a change:

```
onclick="submitSQLNoteText();"
```

which runs:

```
function submitSQLNoteText()
{
    var noteid = <?php if(isset($_POST['sqlnoteid'])){ echo $_POST['sqlnoteid'];} ?>;
    var notetext = $("#ta4").text();
    var data = {noteid1: noteid, notetext1: notetext};

    if(noteid == ''||notetext == '')
    {
        alert("NoteID or Text is blank");
    }
    else
    {   
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "submitSQLNoteText.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){
                alert("Success");
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
};
```

The submitSQLNoteText.php file:

```
if (isset($_POST['noteid1'], $_POST['notetext1'])) 
{

    $noteid2 = $_POST['noteid1'];
    $notetext2 = html_entity_decode($_POST['notetext1']);

    $stmt = "UPDATE SQLNotes SET SQLNote = (?) WHERE SQLNoteID = (?)";
    $params = array($notetext2, $noteid2);

    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $stmt, $params);

    if ($stmt === false) 
    {
        die( print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
}
```

So why am i losing my line breaks?

Comment: you also seem to have some html markup that need to be ticked `\`` in order to highlight those. Ones such as `<br>` that are not showing and possibly more. Edit: I fixed those for you @LukeLitherland

Comment: Might be a little **LOW TEC** for you but did you consider `str_replace("\n", '<br>', $astring);`

Comment: @RiggsFolly i have indeed, but no luck :(

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you! I'll remember thatt for next time.

Comment: @LukeLitherland welcome. You may have to include (more/the) HTML for this. I might not be able to help but others may pick up on something. This could also be related to the JSON and `html_entity_decode()` but I can't be 100% sure about it.

Comment: It's worth saying that it is generally better practice to keep the newlines as `\n` when saving to the database, and only swap for `<br>` when outputting as HTML. The same goes for other formatting -- the stored data should be in the raw format wherever possible.

Comment: @Fred-ii- hmmm could actually be the JSON, i just looked in the network tab of the dev tools and its showing the text that is being sent to the database, so essentially the text that has been parsed throught the AJAX request and the line breaks are already missing.